# does the countinous function over continuous function is continuous?

Tags: continuity

If I have a function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ which is continuous and $f:\Omega \rightarrow [0,1]$ which is right continuous. Is $g(f)$ continuous or just right continuous? Here $\Omega$ is the event space and $f$ is a random variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it will only be right-continuous as we can take $g(x)=x$ and then $g\circ f=f$.

Comment: any formal way to prove this property?

Comment: That is a formal proof. Just pick any function $f$ that is right-continuous and not continuous, then $g \circ f = f$ is right-continuous and not continuous.

Comment: Or which property do you mean?

Comment: yeah got it thanks

Comment: You're welcome.